# How to work with HTTP Post in android?

Tags: php, android, http-post

i am new to android and i am following the simple example code available http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89
Here is the source code:

```
public class HTTPPostEx extends ActionBarActivity {

    TextView content;
    EditText fname, email, login, pass;
    String Name, Email, Login, Pass;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_httppost_ex);

        content    =   (TextView)findViewById( R.id.textView6);
        fname      =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        email      =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        login      =    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        pass       =   (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);


        Button saveme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        saveme.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                try{   

                    GetText();
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    content.setText(" url exeption! " );
                }
            }
        });
    }   

    public  void  GetText()  throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {          
        Name = fname.getText().toString();
        Email   = email.getText().toString();
        Login   = login.getText().toString();
        Pass   = pass.getText().toString();

        // Create data variable for sent values to server

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Name, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Login, "UTF-8");

        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("pass", "UTF-8")+ "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Pass, "UTF-8");

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        // Send data
        try
        {  

            URL url = new URL("http://androidexample.com/media/webservice/httppost.php");


            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write( data );
            wr.flush();

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

           while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }


            text = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {

                reader.close();
            }

            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }

        content.setText( text  );

    }}
```

There is nothing wrong with this code. But i am not able to post data on web.
 here is the logcat output:

```
    02-13 14:10:04.986  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 14:10:04.986  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample E/error﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
            at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
            at com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample.HTTPPostEx.GetText(HTTPPostEx.java:93)
            at com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample.HTTPPostEx$1.onClick(HTTPPostEx.java:48)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 14:10:04.986  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 14:10:04.986  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample.HTTPPostEx.GetText(HTTPPostEx.java:124)
02-13 14:10:04.986  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample.HTTPPostEx$1.onClick(HTTPPostEx.java:48)
02-13 14:10:04.986  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
02-13 14:10:04.986  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338)
02-13 14:10:04.986  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-13 14:10:04.986  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-13 14:10:04.996  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 14:10:04.996  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
02-13 14:10:04.996  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 14:10:04.996  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 14:10:04.996  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
02-13 14:10:04.996  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
02-13 14:10:04.996  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 14:10:04.996  22550-22550/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample E/error﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample.HTTPPostEx.GetText(HTTPPostEx.java:124)
            at com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample.HTTPPostEx$1.onClick(HTTPPostEx.java:48)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4432)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18338)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anybody please help me to understand how it will work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What response getting in `text = sb.toString();` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK-- i am getting nothing :(

Comment: Look at this [code](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

Comment: @Param : `neither i am getting error on button click` because you are catching `Exception` exception and not using `ex.printStackTrace();` in any `catch` block that's why error is not showing in log. add `ex.printStackTrace();` every `catch` block to get exception log

Comment: @JoanColmenero- yes this code is easy but what about my code? what's wrong with it? can u plz explain. Is it wrong way?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK- after using it i am getting on logcat :: `com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
02-13 13:37:20.330  15711-15711/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample.HTTPPostEx.GetText(HTTPPostEx.java:90)
02-13 13:37:20.340  15711-15711/com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample W/System.err﹕ at com.funkiorangetech.httppostexample.HTTPPostEx$1.onClick(HTTPPostEx.java:47)
 `

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK- on lines: `OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());` and `GetText();`

Comment: @Param: please add entire log with question

Comment: @Param try catching Exception like `Log.e("error", Log.getStackTraceString(e)` and seek for the relevant error there.

Comment: @sitilge- i have done with that and edited the question with logcat error. please see and assist me .

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException ? Seriously ?

Comment: @2Dee- provide the solution please :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the reason why i am getting this error. i just checked out [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html/) and came to know i shouldn't use the code like this. Instead i should use Thread and handlers to handle the HTTP calls. Well Thanks everybody for your assistance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the link below to get the solutions :

1. The below link explains with a beautiful example http://androidexample.com/How_To_Make_HTTP_POST_Request_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=64&aaid=89
2. Excecuting an Http post request with httpclient http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: i used the same example :(

Comment: But it had tried the example it works completely fine...recheck the code.